# Angular 7 PWA does not updates in iOS Safari

Tags: angular, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I am new to Angular and got managed to develop a basic Progressive Web Application. I was successful in creating desktop shortcuts of the web app on both iOS 12.2 and Android.

I was building a logic so that the app could get refreshed/reload when there is an update on the server. Chrome app has no issue, however the safari based app does not get updated.

Here is the code:-

```
constructor(private updates: SwUpdate) {
    updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      updates.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi there.... I have the exact same issue. I am using 'interval' to check for an update every 15 minutes. The code is getting executed but for some reason the update is not detected in Safari... works like a charm in other browsers.
Did you find a solution to this?